# Automatic repetition of mathematical operators after a line break

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

In handwritten mathematics it is common for the sake of clarity to repeat the last mathematical operator in those line breaks that occur in the middle of a formula. I mean something like:

```
We compute 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +
+ 6 + 7 + 8 to know the answer.
```

In LaTeX I always do this repetition in displayed environments such as align or multline by manually adding the symbol after the `\\` but this is much more difficult in inline formulas because the breaking point may change during different compilations. In this case I only do it occasionally for the multiplication \cdot. Anyway, this makes my mathematical style not coherent, so I would like to know if there is any package to implement this option.

If you think that this practice is bad I would like to read the reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have always considered this repetition a peculiarity of Russian typesetting, see e.g. 
http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb17-4/tb53grin.pdf. The article http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb16-4/tb49olga.pdf claims existence of a package you are looking for, but it's nowhere to be found.

Anyway, one Denis Ryabov took this into his hands and translated Grinchuk's ideas from the articles above into code: http://d-ryabov.livejournal.com/723.html. Copy the text from the page, paste into a file named `rumathbr.sty`, include it by `\usepackage{rumathbr}` and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thank you. I have found a newer version of this package in http://joomup.com/rumathbr.sty and I have uncommented a line to make the `\cdot` a breakable symbol. In the comment he says that he wants to implement it so that the `\cdot` becomes a `\times` in the case of a line break, but I do not follow this practice and I always use a repeated `\cdot`.

Comment: By the way, I am Catalan and I did not know the Russian origin of this tradition. I know many people in here that use it in handwritten mathematics, but I cannot say that they form a vast majority.

Comment: Current version at https://github.com/dryabov/rmathbr

Answer (score 2):

A lightweight solution from Cherepanov's `russadd.sty`:

```
\def\hm#1{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}{\hbox{\m@th$#1$}}{}}
% usage: $a\hm+b\hm=c$
```

Comment: (Of course, one has to add `\hm`s by hand...)