# What is the correct way to properly align a split equation with continued parts prefixed with a binary operator?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

Consider the following result with 2 methods. Don't hesitate to propose better ones if any.

[image]

The question is: What is the correct way to properly align a split equation in which binary operator appears at the beginning of the continued parts?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section*{quad}
\[
\begin{split}
\text{LHS} 
&= c + d\\
&\quad +e +f +g
\end{split}
\]

\section*{phantom}
\[
\begin{split}
\text{LHS} 
&= c + d\\
&\hphantom{{}=} +e +f +g
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first thing I would think is: is there a proper alignment? (Not talking about how to align, but rather the point of alignment.) I don't think so. Unlike manye equations where you can easily think that aligning at the `=` is right, here you can align at many different (and no so defined) points.

Comment: The only rule I know says that you shouldn't align with the left side of the equal sign (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172110). So Manuel is right. There could be many points. I also use your style (vert. aligned right side of the `=`) and therefore would tend to the second version. This version yields a perfect alignment. Can't imagine that `\quad` always will.

Comment: agreed that there's no definitive rule for such alignment.  knuth uses `\qquad` after the alignment point for a continued formula (*texbook*, page 195).  [*mathematics into type*](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf) shows several possibilities, including those already mentioned (pages 46ff.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer one of these 3 variants, that use the amsmath environments (the second one, not very convincing here, might be of interest for longer formulae):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\section*{variant 1:}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= \begin{aligned}[t]
c & + d\\
& +e + f +g
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\section*{variant 2:}
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} & = \begin{multlined}[t]
c + d\\
+e +f +g
\end{multlined}
\end{align*}

\section*{variant 3:}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \text{LHS} & {} = c & + d \\
  & & &+ e + f +g
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the third one you ar missing a `{}`. And in the two others I would add `\!` before the `…ed` environment.

Comment: Thanks, Manuel! You're right, I didn't check enough. Modified the answer. The funny point is that in another (not totally satisfactory) variant, I did have to add a {} in front of a binary  operator…

Comment: The code is not synced with the output image, I think.

Comment: You're right. I *thought* I had loaded the new output image, but I didn't for some reason (probably forgot to validate my upload°). Now it's sync'ed.