# equation goes out of margin

Tags: math-mode

```
\[
 \left| \dfrac{(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k\beta_k z^k}{B(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)] 
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k -[(A-B)(1-\alpha)][z+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k]}\right|<1
\]
```

Comment: `\[\scriptscriptstyle\left|\frac{...\right|<1\]`

Comment: @Werner, LaRiFaRi -- This new query by Mittal is *not* a duplicate of his earlier query. The earlier query was about a multiline equation; this new one is about a single equation that has a very long expression in the denominator. The solution techniques for the earlier query do not apply here.

Comment: @Mico: True, it may very well not be a duplicate. I just didn't find the question all that useful, nor did it show any research effort at all. In my opinion, a poorly stated question, period.

Comment: @Werner - In that case, the question should be closed because it's not clear what is being asked or because it's low quality, right?

Comment: @Mico Right. But it seems like the OP is having the very same issue as in her/his other post. Over there are 6 nice answers on splitting over-long equations and none has been accepted. DINESH, as shrinking the font size is not really an option (I just posted that comment, as you asked for it *later*), this "question" is clearly a duplicate on your other post.

Comment: sir i am writing manuscript and many of my equation have long either denominator or numerator i cannto split equation in two parts what will i do so that my equation comes with in the margin

Comment: @DINESHMITTAL You will have to help your readers to understand your formulae. And they have to be able to read it in terms of visibility. Therefore you have to split them or you use help-variables like in Micos nice answer. If your equations are that big, they are just *too* big and will not be read with full interest. In order to split long denominators and numerators: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172110

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you break this equation into two separate expressions: The first to define the numerator term (which also reoccurs in the first part of the denominator) as "C", and the second to express the full result in terms of "C".

Alternatively, you could use the `\splitfrac` macro of the `mathtools` package to break the long denominator across two lines. If you choose this method, you'll probably need to place delimiters, e.g., curly braces, around the denominator.

I would *not* recommend scaling the full expression down to make it fit within the textblock: The font will become so tiny as to be virtually illegible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for \splitfrac macro
\usepackage{graphicx}   % for \resizebox macro
\begin{document}

\hrule %% just to illustrate the width of the text block
\bigskip

Put
\[ \textstyle C = (1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k\beta_k z^k\,.
\]
Then
\[
 \left\lvert \dfrac{C}{BC -\bigl[(A-B)(1-\alpha)\bigr]\bigl[z+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k\bigr]}\right\rvert<1\,.
\]


\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\[
\left\lvert \dfrac{(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k\beta_k z^k}{
 \splitfrac{\Bigl\{B(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)] 
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k }{-\bigl[(A-B)(1-\alpha)\bigr]\bigl[z+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k\bigr]\Bigr\}}}
\right\vert<1\,.
\]

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

Using \verb+\resizebox+ (not recommended!):

\medskip\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
$
 \left| \dfrac{(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k\beta_k z^k}{B(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)] 
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k -[(A-B)(1-\alpha)][z+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k]}\right|<1
$
}

\bigskip
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: can i small the text size of this equation only

Comment: @DINESHMITTAL - I've added a solution method that uses the `\splitfrac` macro of the `mathtools` package.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you use landscape layout.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
 \left| \dfrac{(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k\beta_k z^k}{B(1-\beta e^{i\theta}) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)[1+\gamma(k-1)] 
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k -[(A-B)(1-\alpha)][z+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[1+\gamma(k-1)]
 \alpha_k \beta_k z^k]}\right|<1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i cannot use one equation as landscape.

Comment: What you posted gave almost zero information about your problem, and was not even a question. How is anyone to know you can't use `landscape` mode, or what kind of document you're working on? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.