# Proper way of formatting equation strings

Tags: equations, align

In much of my writing, I end up formatting relatively long strings of equations; for example,

```
\begin{align*}
  M &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}x\,dz\,dx\,dy \\
    &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} xz\big\lvert_{z=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,dx\,dy \\
    &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy \\
    &= \cdots
\end{align*}
```

This creates one equation per line. For long collections of equations, this has a somewhat unnatural "snaky" look.

However, I have been told in the past by tech editors that the alternative, which essentially amounts to squeezing all the equations you can onto one line, like this:

```
\begin{align*}
  M &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}x\,dz\,dx\,dy 
     = \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} xz\big\lvert_{z=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,dx\,dy \\
    &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy 
     = \cdots
\end{align*}
```

is poor practice, because it's easy to miss an equation inside a line (and I pretty much agree with this). Is there generally accepted practice, or what do other people do in this situation? (Of course, breaking up the list of equations is one approach, but that is not always a natural thing to do either).

Comment: Personally, I'd encourage clarity over "snakyness" (whatever that means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Personally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172110), I try to never put two equal-signs on one line. If you think, your equations are getting to long, you could split them up into several and give the reader some little rest. Just start with an `M` again or get the very first expression back in mind by repeating it.

The best way, however, is to guide your reader through your formula by adding some little explanations. This is real luxury for the person reading your maths and it helps to get your snakes dismembered. In my MWE I use some explanation for every line; just for show. This would be a bit exaggerated in most cases.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    M &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}x\,dz\,dx\,dy \\
    \shortintertext{then}
    &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} xz\bigg\lvert_{z=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,dx\,dy \\
    \intertext{bla blup, something longer, Lorem Ipsum... QED!}
    &= \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy \\
    \shortintertext{finally: dots}
    &= \cdots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]