# Move second line in an equation to the left with split

Tags: equations

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,&z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
&\prod_{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset} \left( \left|z_{w_jpa} - a\right| + \left(-1\right)^{|z_{w_jpa} - a|} w_j\right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The result of this code is [image: here]
I want to move the second line of the equation to the left so that the equation label does not use another line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\hspace*{-15pt}` after `&` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,&z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
&\hspace*{-15pt}\prod_{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset}     \left( \left|z_{w_jpa} - a\right| + \left(-1\right)^{|z_{w_jpa} - a|} w_j\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

 \hspace* ensures that the space is given unlike other 
\hspace, \hskip commands especially when given at the 
beginning of the line.
```

Comment: One last thing. It has to be `,{}&z`

Answer (score 4):

You may define this by the placement of the align-command `&`. At the moment you are aligning the left side of your product to the `z` of the line above. Just play around with those placements.

Two remarks: Do not type `\\` on your last line. If you align to the `,z` in your first line, you will disable the automatic spacing after the comma. Please do `,{}&z` instead.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{7}
% without any alignment.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,z_{w_{1\mathrm{pa}}},\ldots,z_{w_{m\mathrm{pa}}},a) = \\
        \prod_{\mathclap{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} \neq \emptyset}} \bigl( |z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} - a| + (-1)^{|z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} - a|} w_j\bigr)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

% aligned left
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,z_{w_{1\mathrm{pa}}},\ldots,z_{w_{m\mathrm{pa}}},a) = \\
        &\prod_{\mathrlap{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} \neq \emptyset}} \bigl( |z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} - a| + (-1)^{|z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} - a|} w_j\bigr)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

% aligned to the z as in your MWE
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,{}&z_{w_{1\mathrm{pa}}},\ldots,z_{w_{m\mathrm{pa}}},a) = \\
        &\prod_{\mathclap{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} \neq \emptyset}} \bigl( |z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} - a| + (-1)^{|z_{w_{j\mathrm{pa}}} - a|} w_j\bigr)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

off-topic: I would recommend to write the = on the second line. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172110

Answer (score 4):

Delete the last `\\`.
I propose four other variants, of which `multlined` requires loading `mathtools`  instead of `amsmath`; one has the whole equation on one line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) =\\%
  \prod  _{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\} ∣z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset} \bigl( \abs{z_{w_jpa} - a} + \left(-1\right)^{\abs{z_{w_jpa} - a}} w_j\bigr)
\end{multline}
\vskip 0.5cm

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,{}&z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
    &\prod  _{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\} ∣z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset} \left( \abs{z_{w_jpa} - a} + \left(-1\right)^{\abs{z_{w_jpa} - a}} w_j\right)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\vskip 0.5cm

\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
    f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m, z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
    \prod  _{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\} ∣z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset} \left( \abs{z_{w_jpa} - a} + \left(-1\right)^{\abs{z_{w_jpa} - a}} w_j\right)
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}%
\vskip 0.5cm

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \MoveEqLeft f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m, z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
      & \prod  _{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\} ∣z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset} \left( \abs{z_{w_jpa} - a} + \left(-1\right)^{\abs{z_{w_jpa} - a}} w_j\right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}%
\vskip 0.5cm

\begin{equation}
  f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,{}z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
  \prod  _{\mathclap{\substack{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\} \\ z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset}}}\!\left( \abs{z_{w_jpa} - a} + \left(-1\right)^{\abs{z_{w_jpa} - a}} w_j\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing it. I change that at once!

Comment: your are welcome. with `,{}&` you even get my vote :-)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I even added a fifth solution:o)

Comment: uh, like that one. And +1 it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `multline`; I changed the complicated subscript by using `\substack` that avoids making it too long. Note that I'd prefer the first unadjusted version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is the default rendering
\begin{multline}
f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
\prod_{\substack{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \\ z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset}} 
  \Bigl( \lvert z_{w_jpa} - a\rvert + (-1)^{|z_{w_jpa} - a|} w_j\Bigr)
\end{multline}
and this happens if you add some balanced spaces
\begin{multline}
\hspace{4em}
f_a(w_1,\ldots,w_m,z_{w_1pa},\ldots,z_{w_mpa},a) = \\
\prod_{\substack{j\in \{1,\ldots,m\} \\ z_{w_jpa} \neq \emptyset}} 
  \Bigl( \lvert z_{w_jpa} - a\rvert + (-1)^{|z_{w_jpa} - a|} w_j\Bigr)
\hspace{4em}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't the `=`'s be moved down to the second line?

Comment: @daleif Personal preferences.